# A quick question about Einstein's summation

Tags: notation, vectors, inner-products, index-notation

I am not familiar with Einstein's summation convention. On p.5 of the book *Mathematics of Classical and Quantum Physics* written by Bryon and Fuller, the authors wrote:
$$\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y=x_iy_j\delta_{ij}\color{red}{=x_iy_j}=x_jy_j.$$
Why is the sum equal to $x_iy_j$? Since the expression does not contain any repeated indices, is it even a sum?

Comment: what is in red, is wrong

Comment: Yeah ... Looks like a typo ...

Comment: @janmarqz Put aside the question of whether the sum is equal to $x_iy_j$ or not. Is $x_iy_j$ a valid summation notation?

Comment: Where an indicie is repeated twice, implicitly this means to sum on that index. $x_i y_j$ does not have any implied sum ... it means take the component $x_i$ and multply it by the component $y_j$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks a lot for the explanation. Would you please make it into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall, there, Donald Splutterwit, has cleared your doubt

Comment: @janmarqz Yes, and thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where an index is repeated twice, implicitly this means to sum on that index. $x_iy_j$ does not have any implied sum ... it means take the component $x_i$ and multiply it by the component $y_j$.

This could be used to define a matrix
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_{i,j}=x_i y_j.
\end{eqnarray*}